# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol public: static class

Tags: c++, linker-errors, static-members

I cannot figure out why i am recieving this error. Can anyone lend a hand.
I need to declare VideoCapture capture in the header file and call it in Video.cpp

**Video.h**

```
class Video
{
    public:

    static VideoCapture capture;

    //Default constructor
    Video();

    //Declare a virtual destructor:
    virtual ~Video();

    //Method
    void Start();   

    private:
};
```

**Video.cpp**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Video.h"
#include "UserInfo.h"
#include "Common.h"

void Video::Start()
{
  while(1)
  {
    Mat img;

    bool bSuccess = capture.read(img); // read a new frame from video

     if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
                    cout << "End of video" << endl;
                   break;
    }

    imshow("original video", img); //show the frame in "Original Video" window

    if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
   {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl; 
            break; 
   }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a class definition, `static` variables are a merely a *declaration*.  You have only declared that `capture` will exist *somewhere*.

You need to add the *definition*.  Make the variable exist.

**In any version of C++**

You can separately define the variable in your cpp file.

```
const VideoCapture Video::capture;
```

**In C++ 17 or later**

You can declare the variable `inline` in your header to make it a definition.

```
static inline VideoCapture capture;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can add the definition of VideoCapture Video::capture?

Comment: @user3743939 That's in my answer.  :)